# PreBuild for PreBuild Event Command in csproj

Tags: msbuild, csproj

Can I specify in csproj file that the exe being executed in prebuild events should be built before executing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Visual Studio which will actually edit your .csproj file in fact.

Right click on the project and select Project Dependencies and select the project which you need to build before this project. Verify it by selecting the Build order tab.

Comment: aren't the dependencies build after PreBuild events are executed?