# Is there Visual Studio 2012 Pre-Run Event?

Tags: visual-studio

I am hoping to run a batch file before running the exe from visual studio. Therefore, is there a pre-run event?

Why I am doing this. There are generated assets from other exe, and I want to copy over the newer assets automatically before running this exe.

To clarify, this should work without building from Visual Studio. Assume the build/exe to stay the same.

Comment: The IDE automation interface (EnvDte) has an [OnEnterRunMode event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debuggereventsclass.onenterrunmode.aspx).  Writing an add-in to take advantage of it is a month of your life you'll never get back.  Whatever tool you use to generate the "assets" can just as well put them in the right place so you don't need this at all.

Comment: Thanks man, that might be just what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out actually pre-build event is also pre-run event.
Everytime before running, it tries to figure out if it needs to build, so even if it doesn't build anything, it always runs the pre-build event.

Answer (score 0):

VS project file is basically MSBuild file and MS Build provides such events.
Open your .csproj file in text editor and you will see plain MS Build xml file.

See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx

Also, this question suggests: [PreBuild for PreBuild Event Command in csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426029/prebuild-for-prebuild-event-command-in-csproj)

> You can do it through Visual Studio which will actually edit your
>   .csproj file in fact.
>
> Right click on the project and select Project Dependencies and select
>   the project which you need to build before this project. Verify it by
>   selecting the Build order tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However I am looking for a pre-run event, and not post-build/pre-build event. Since the data could be generated w/o building a new build.

Comment: What kind of data? How are you running exe from visual studio? F5? What should happen if I run this exe outside of VS? If sources were not changed, VS won't produce new build/exe

Comment: Yup, I meant f5 to run, but there is no code change.
I want it to run a batch file right before I run everytime.